# Having issues following an equality (Vector Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I'm given that
$$\vec E =\frac{\mu_0p_0\omega^2}{4\pi r}\Big[\cos u\Big(\hat x-\frac{x}{r}\hat r\Big)+\sin u \Big(\hat y-\frac{y}{r}\hat r\Big)\Big]$$
implies
$$-\frac{\mu_0p_0\omega^2}{4\pi r}\Big[\cos u\hat x\times \hat r + \sin u \hat y \times \hat r\Big]=\frac{1}{c}\hat r \times \vec E,$$
but I don't follow how to get from the former to the latter.

Could someone connect the dots for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the second equation by taking the cross product of the first one with  $\frac{1}{c} \hat{r}$ on the left and remembering that $\vec{x} \times \vec{x} = \vec{0}$, so in particular $\hat{r} \times \hat{r} = \vec{0}$; and also that $\hat{r}\times\hat{x} = - \hat{x} \times \hat{r}$.

Comment: I don't follow, when I expand the terms in brackets for the former I get a set of sums, I don't see cross products anywhere.

Comment: Check the rewording of the answer: does it make any more sense now?

Comment: I can see how they're related now! But is there something in the form of the RHS of the former that I should have recognized to make the conversion to the LHS of the latter, or does it just come with practice?

Comment: I don't know why the two equations were presented in "opposite order": I would have made $\frac{1}{c}\hat{r} \times \vec{E}$ the LHS of (2). It would then be much clearer (IMO) how to get from (1) to (2).